# Magento 2 : On paypal orders billing information displaying incorrect format in admin order

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, paypal, magento2.3.1

My recent upgrade is 2.3.2 as Magento moves we are upgrading one by one, but we are having an issue which is on Paypal orders we are getting variable prefixes in billing address as an email template format. **Is there any fix relates to its.**

> I tried few solutions who got fixed earlier but no luck, In database also I checked
>   it is perfect. But why it is not fixed yet. We didn't touch anything
>   in code.

**Please help me to get the best solution for this.**

[image]

Comment: i am getting this issue find any solution 
???

Comment: This might be the issue of the format of the billing address saved in the customer configuration section.

Comment: there is no customization on this in the backend. default issue and reported to Magento. they were able to reproduce the issue.